# Javascript memory leak when changing model data in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, memory-leaks

We're building a fairly large one-page-application with KnockoutJS as "data-handler".

The problem is that when changing model-data, the old models isn't disposed by the garbage collector (as it seems).

The application has about 12 different models with computed obserables that you can retreive relations with.

In the ViewModel I have a observable array for each of the model. Lets say I fill a array with 100 instances of a model. When I later want to change these 100 to 100 different instances the memory grows and it never goes down (I'm using Chrome and checking the in the Windows Task Manager).

The application is quite complex but I'll give some examples of what I'm doing (code is copied and simplified to only show some examples, some of the code might seem to be strange but its problably because I removed namespacing and other stuff).

**ViewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = (function () {
    var _departments = ko.observableArray(),
        _addresses = ko.observableArray();

    var UpdateData = function (data) {

        if (typeof data.departments != 'undefined') {
            var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.departments, function(item) {
                return new Department(item);
            });
            _departments(mappedData);
        }

        if (typeof data.addresses != 'undefined') {
            var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.addresses , function(item) {
                return new Address(item);
            });
            _addresses (mappedData );
        }
    };

    return {
        departments: _departments,
        addresses: _addresses,
        UpdateData: UpdateData
    };

})();
```

**Department model**

```
var Department = function (data) {

    var Department = {
        Id: ko.observable(data.ClusterId),
        Number: ko.observable(data.Number),
        Name: ko.observable(data.Name)
    };

    var Addresses = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(ViewModel.addresses(), function (address) {
            return address.DepartmentId() === Department.Id();
        }).sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.Number() < b.Number() ? -1 : 1;
        });
    }, Department);

    var Update = function (data) {
        Department.Id(data.Id);
        Department.Number(data.Number);
        Department.Name(data.Name);
    };

    $.extend(Department, {
        Addresses: Addresses,
        Update: Update
    });

    return Department;

};
```

**Address model**

```
var Address = function (data) {

    var Address = {
        Id: ko.observable(data.Id),
        Number: ko.observable(data.Number),
        Text: ko.observable(data.Text),
        DepartmentId: ko.observable(data.DepartmentId)
    };

    var Department = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(ViewModel.departments(), function (item) {
            return item.Id() == Address.DepartmentId();
        });
    }, Address);

    var Update = function (data) {
        Address.Id(data.Id);
        Address.Number(data.Number);
        Address.Text(data.Text);
        Address.DepartmentId(data.DepartmentId);
    };

    $.extend(Address, {
        Department: Department,
        Update: Update
    });

    return Address;

};
```

There are alot more code but what I'm looking for is a way to start finding the leak (I have tried to find it for some hours now). Is there something in my example that could cause it? Or has anyone else had this kind of problem? The app also has multiple custom bindings but I've tried to remove the HTML that uses the bindings and it seems that the "raw" javascript object is what taking up the memory.

If I'm changing the observable & computed variables in the models to functions that return a static value the objects seems to be disposed.

Comment: Did you try manually start the garbage collector? When you open Console, pick Timeline and on the bottom, 6th icon from the left corner is a button "Collect garbage". See if RAM usage drops. If it does, that would mean you have too much RAM for amount of RAM used so garbage collector is sitting idle because it's not needed to run it right now. (It's lazy!!!!)

Comment: Just to clarify: you are using the latest version of knockout library?

Comment: Yeah recently updated to the latest

Comment: Tried to manually garbage collect, it "removed" some of the memory but its still increasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `computed's` within each `Department` and `Address` will keep their subscription to the viewmodel until you swap out both departments and addresses.  For example, I would expect this to leak memory:

```
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
ViewModel.UpdateData({ departments: [ /* some new departments */ ] });
```

In this case, all of the "old" departments will still be bound to your `ViewModel.Addresses`.  Changing out the `Addresses` should then release the memory:

```
ViewModel.UpdateData({ addresses: [ /* some new addresses */ ]});
// all the old departments should get GC'd now.
```

One way to resolve this is to modify your `ViewModel` to dispose of the old objects before removing them:

```
var ViewModel = (function () {
var _departments = ko.observableArray(),
    _addresses = ko.observableArray();

var UpdateData = function (data) {

    if (typeof data.departments != 'undefined') {
        var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.departments, function(item) {
            return new Department(item);
        });

        // dispose of the computeds in the old departments
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_departments(), function (d) { d.Addresses.dispose(); });
        _departments(mappedData);
    }

    if (typeof data.addresses != 'undefined') {
        var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.addresses , function(item) {
            return new Address(item);
        });
        // dispose of the computeds in the old addresses
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_addresses(), function (a) { a.Department.dispose(); });
        _addresses (mappedData );
    }
};

return {
    departments: _departments,
    addresses: _addresses,
    UpdateData: UpdateData
};

})();
```

Read the [Knockout Computed Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).  Specifically scroll to the bottom and read the documentation for `dispose`.  Make sure you `dispose` of any computeds you create if they are being removed but the observables they are depending upon are not being removed.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. I actually thought that computed observables would be automatically disposed by knockout someway.

Comment: it cleans up the ones it creates for its html bindings.  Otherwise it relies on the GC, which will only clean them up when all references are removed to both the computed and its dependencies.  When you have a case where the lifetime of the computed is less than the lifetime of the dependencies then you have to dispose it yourself.