# Java script memory got increased after refreshing tab

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

We are using knock out js components loading on telerik:RadTab. After switching between memory increasing...

I tried to clear the all global variables and dom elemnts of tab before  refreshing tab.

Please let me how we can release the java script memory using java script?

Comment: yea, I opened the page in private mode. Memory increased to double while switching tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like memory leak problem.
Check this thread for reference.

[Javascript memory leak when changing model data in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049338/javascript-memory-leak-when-changing-model-data-in-knockoutjs)